# Difficulties with launchd executing python script

Tags: macos, launchd

I am trying to use launchd to run a python script every 10 minutes. This is easy with cron, but I have been trying for several hours to understand how to operate launchd and I have been unsuccessful. I am using a version of python located in `/Users/turtle/bin/`. Here is what my launchd file (`com.foobar`) looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>com.foobar</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
            <string>/Users/turtle/bin/python</string>
            <string>/Users/turtle/code/baz.py</string>
        </array>
        <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Minute</key>
            <integer>10</integer>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

When I run:

`launchctl load /Library/LaunchAgents/com.foobar`

I get:

`launchctl: Couldn't stat("/Library/LaunchAgents/com.foobar"): No such file or directory nothing found to load`

Can anyone help me? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**StartCalendarInterval** with the key **Minute** : the script run at the 10th minutes of every hour.

You must use **StartInterval** : job to be started every N **seconds**

```
<key>StartInterval</key>
<integer>600</integer>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchAgents/com.foobar
```

Does that work?

Comment: Thanks for the help. Unfortunately, I already tried the `-w` flag, but it didn't work.

Comment: If I add `.plist` to the file name it now loads, but the python script still doesn't execute.